# jQuery. Способ вывода значения атрибута в html при наведении

Tags: jquery

```
<a href="www.tut.by">Ссылка 1</a>
<a href="www.lenta.ru">Ссылка 2</a>
<a href="www.rambler.ru">Ссылка 3</a>
```

При наведении на содержимое ссылки (к примеру, "Ссылка 1") она должна поменяться на значение атрибута href в круглых скобках (была "Ссылка 1", а стала "(www.tut.by)"). Максимум, до чего дошёл, :

```
$('a').on('mouseover',function(){
    $(this).html().attr('href');
})
```

Но он не работает...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Почти всё так. Только надо в `html` помещать значение атрибута, а ты делал `get` содержимого ссылки и потом `get` атрибута.

```js
$('a').on('mouseover',function(){
    $(this).html($(this).attr('href'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="www.tut.by">Ссылка 1</a>
<a href="www.lenta.ru">Ссылка 2</a>
<a href="www.rambler.ru">Ссылка 3</a>
```

---

типа toggle

```js
$('a').on('mouseover', function() {  
  $(this).data('mouseleave', $(this).html());
  $(this).html($(this).attr('href'));
})

$('a').on('mouseleave', function() { 
  $(this).html($(this).data('mouseleave'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="www.tut.by">Ссылка 1</a>
<a href="www.lenta.ru">Ссылка 2</a>
<a href="www.rambler.ru">Ссылка 3</a>
```

Comment: Супер! Спасибо!